# How to create id attributes for <h2> and <h3> tags based on a portion of their respective innerHTML?

Tags: php, html

I have a customer who uses TinyMCE TOC, but who does not appreciate the random IDs that the plugin adds to the heading tags (`<h2>` and `<h3>`).

I want to create a script that parses an article, targets every h2 and h3 tag, then creates `id` attributes from the text they contain.

I thought I could do this with `preg_replace_callback()`, but when I use the function, I realize that there are certain situations where it does not work.

For example, it doesn't work if the h2/h3's text starts with a space, a number, etc.

Here is an early attempt that worked in some cases:

```
function function_to_makeItClear($string) {
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $string = str_ireplace(' ', '-', $string);
    return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); 
}

function betterId($match){
    $escape = str_split(strip_tags($match[2]), 20);
    $id = strlen($escape[0]) >=5 ? function_to_makeItClear($escape[0]) : str_shuffle('AnyWordsHere');
    return '<h'.$match[1].' id="'.$id.'">'.$match[2].'</h'.$match[1].'>';
}
return preg_replace_callback('#<h([1-6]).*?>(.*?)<\/h[1-6]>#si', 'betterId', $texte);
```

Here is some sample text I want to transform:

```
<p>Paragraph one is okay </p>
<h2>This will work without problem</h2>
<p>Paragraph two is okay </p>
<h2><a href="#">This heading has anchor</a></h2>
<p>Paragraph one is okay </p>
<h2>  This heading start with space</h2>
<p>Paragraph two is okay </p>
<h3>1. <a href="https://www.example1.com/">This wont work</a></h3>
<p>Paragraph one is okay </p>
<h3>2. <a href="https://www.example2.com/">Not working</a></h3>
<p>Paragraph two is okay </p>
<h3>3. Neither this one</h3>
<h3>But this works again</h3>
```

I would like to have this result:

```
<p>Paragraph one is okay </p>
<h2 id="this-will-work">This will work without problem</h2>
<p>Paragraph two is okay </p>
<h2 id="this-heading-has"><a href="#">This heading has anchor</a></h2>
<p>Paragraph one is okay </p>
<h2 id="this-heading-start">  This heading start with space</h2>
<p>Paragraph two is okay </p>
<h3 id="this-wont-work">1. <a href="https://www.example1.com/">This wont work</a></h3>
<p>Paragraph one is okay </p>
<h3 id="not-working">2. <a href="https://www.example2.com/">Not working</a></h3>
<p>Paragraph two is okay </p>
<h3 id="neighter-this-one">3. Neither this one</h3>
<h3 id="but-this-works">But this works again</h3>
```

UPDATE:

I have since implemented a different approach using a DOM parser with great results, but there are still some scenarios where it fails and I have to manually add `id`s myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DOMDocument and its good friend XPath to reliably extract the heading tags from your valid html.

Use `nodeValue()` to generate a tag-free string from the heading tag's innerHTML.  ([Demonstration of what nodeValue() generates](https://3v4l.org/LGJK9))

Use `preg_match()` to exclude the leading spaces and numbers, then match the first one, two, or three words. ([A slightly altered demonstration of the pattern](https://regex101.com/r/mBRlWi/1))

If there is a match containing at least one word, replace spaces with hyphens and add that string as the id attribute.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/27IaK))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div>
<p>Paragraph one is okay </p>
<h2>This will work without problem</h2>
<p>Paragraph two is okay </p>
<h2><a href="#">This heading has anchor</a></h2>
<p>Paragraph one is okay </p>
<h2>  This heading start with space</h2>
<p>Paragraph two is okay </p>
<h3>1. <a href="https://www.example1.com/">This wont work</a></h3>
<p>Paragraph one is okay </p>
<h3>2. <a href="https://www.example2.com/">Not working</a></h3>
<p>Paragraph two is okay </p>
<h3>3. Neither this one</h3>
<h3>But this works again</h3>
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//h2 | //h3") as $node) {
    if (preg_match('~^\s*(?:\d+\.)?\s*\K\S+(?:\s+\S+){1,2}~', $node->nodeValue, $m)) {
        $node->setAttribute('id', str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($m[0])));
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<div>
<p>Paragraph one is okay </p>
<h2 id="this-will-work">This will work without problem</h2>
<p>Paragraph two is okay </p>
<h2 id="this-heading-has"><a href="#">This heading has anchor</a></h2>
<p>Paragraph one is okay </p>
<h2 id="this-heading-start">  This heading start with space</h2>
<p>Paragraph two is okay </p>
<h3 id="this-wont-work">1. <a href="https://www.example1.com/">This wont work</a></h3>
<p>Paragraph one is okay </p>
<h3 id="not-working">2. <a href="https://www.example2.com/">Not working</a></h3>
<p>Paragraph two is okay </p>
<h3 id="neither-this-one">3. Neither this one</h3>
<h3 id="but-this-works">But this works again</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @mickmackusa! The snippet doesn't catch text if the <h2/h3> contains only one word. For example <h3>Google</h3> won't create an ID. Can you please tell me what to change or add the the existing pattern?